# Select2 multiple not getting html selected options using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, dropdown

I am struggling trying to get from my select2 multiple dropdown the html of selected options.

Here my case.

1. I have this standard select2-multiple:

[image: select2-multiple with two selected options]

2. Now I change selection of users, but in console it is not able to take them using jQuery. The code to identify the selected options from dropdown is:

   .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]

So it should be found using this:

```
var selected_users = $('.select2-results__options').find('li .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]').html();
  $('.stakeholders_span').html(selected_users);
  console.log(selected_users);
```

Console log gives always "undefined".

Anyone able to help me :)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is Space in selector after the `li`, should be like

```
'li.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]').html();
  $('.stakeholders_span'
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2-results').select2({templateResult: formatState});
    
    $('.select2-results').on("select2:open", function (e) {                   console.log("open dropdown"); 

      var selected_users = $('.select2-results__options').find('li.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]');
      $("#selected").html(selected_users);
      console.log(selected_users.length+" already selected"); 
    });
    
    
    function formatState (state) {
      var img_url = ($(state.element).attr("url"));
      if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
      var $state = $(
       '<span ><img sytle="display: inline-block;" src="'+img_url+'" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
      );
      return $state;
     }
});
```

```css
select{

width:100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="select2-results" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL" url="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c4ca71c8741234b3699198010d097b0?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">Alabama</option>
  <option value="MU" url="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0eb2e29921d126734f574604f5f0abe8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">MUK</option>
  <option value="WY" url="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bb70a110c197e7e54decf340daffc072?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">Wyoming</option>
</select>

------------
<div id="selected"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test and let you know :)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work on my side. I need to have the html() of the $('.select2-results__options').find('li.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]'), but your solution seems to getting it. Any other idea?

Comment: i dont understand. what is happening and what u need

Comment: Ok, I need to do the following: select multiple choices (they have also images so I need to get the html(), not the text()). Then on click a button I need to see the html of this selected in a div all together. many thanks!

Comment: btw: I am using select2 for bootstrap4

Comment: updated the snippet. Element u are looking for is available when the dropdown is open and its [aria-selected=true] after its reopened.

Comment: Thanks @mastermind. Yes your solution was one of my previous, but now I have to find the way to remove the <li> bullets. Why in your opinion the $('.select2-results__options').find('li.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]'); is not automatically got?

Comment: because this element create dynamically when the dropdown opens

Comment: Hello, your solution seems to being the best. Read my following answer with more details